# Let $f,g : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on (a,b). Show that there exists $\phi$ s.t $f'(\phi) = g'(\phi)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f,g : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$. Suppose that $f(a) = g(a)$, and $f(b) = g(b)$. Show that there exists $\phi \in (a,b)$ such that $f'(\phi) = g'(\phi)$

I think I can use MVT to show the existence of such a point, but I do not understand the real cruz of the problem. I think that for $\phi$, the tangent to the graph of $f$ at $(\phi, f(\phi))$ is parallel to the tangent to the graph on $g$. I am not sure if this is true, but maybe enough to show existence.

Comment: Try to think mean

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Look at $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$. What does $f(a) = g(a)$ imply for $h(a)$? What do we want to happen to $h$ at $\phi$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $h=f-g$. This is a continuous function on $[a,b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$ and takes the value $0$ at $a$ and $b$ so by the MVT there exists $\phi\in(a,b)$ such that $h'(\phi)=0$.

Edit: And yes, your intuition is right; what it is asked to prove is that at some point the slope of the two curves coincides, which means that the tangents to both curves are parallel at that point. It is just simpler to look at $f-g$.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the other answer using MVT is a bit off, because it proves that $f'(x) = g'(y)$ and not as the OP needs $f'(x)=g'(x)$.

The correct answer I think comes from using the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem, which states that for 2 differentiable functions over $(a,b)$, $f$ and $g$, there exists atleast one point $x\in(a,b)$ such that $$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}=\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$.

The result follows easily.